# Using the Weierstrass M-test, show that the series converges uniformly on the given domain

Tags: complex-analysis

$\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{z^k}{z^k+1}$ on the domain $\overline{D}[0, r]$, where $0 \leq r < 1$

I'm honestly not sure how to do this.  My text mentions the Weierstrass M-test but the example they gave after stating it uses a completely different method (looks like a repeat of a previous example) and looks nothing like the M-test.

Answer (score 4):

For $|z|\in [0,r]$, with $0\le r<1$, we have

$$\left|\frac{z^k}{1+z^k}\right|\le \frac{r^k}{1-r}$$

and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k=\frac{1}{1-r}<\infty$

Comment: Mark Viola, do you disagree with user1337? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870028

Comment: @BCLC That solution is fine.  But note that for $0\le r<1$, $r^k<r$ so that $\frac{r^k}{1-r^k}\le \frac{r^k}{1-r}$.

Comment: Thanks Mark Viola! ^-^

Comment: @BCLC You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

From the notation and complex analysis tag I would guess we should assume $z\in \mathbb C,|z|\le r.$ For $k>0,$ we can then say $|1+z^k|\ge 1-|z^k| = 1-|z|^k \ge 1- |z| \ge 1-r.$ Thus

$$\left |\frac{z^k}{1+z^k}\right | = \frac{|z^k|}{|1+z^k|} \le \frac{r^k}{1-r}.$$

Since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} r^k/(1-r) < 1/(1-r)^2,$ we have uniform convergence in $|z|\le r$ by Weierstrass M.

Comment: zhw., do you disagree with user1337? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870028

Comment: @BCLC  user1337 has a valid point. Your bound on $$\left |\frac{z^k}{1+z^k}\right |$$ was not correct.

Comment: Right right, but I meant to ask about the $\frac{r^k}{1-r^k}$. Anyhoo, Mark Viola answered. Thanks anyhoo!