# 2 Exercises on Weierstrass M-test for power series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) 7.29(c),7.30

Please point out errors.

> [image]
>   [image]

Exer 7.29

(c) $M_k = r^k$ because $$\frac{|z|^k}{r^k} \le 1 \le |z^k + 1| $$

Elaboration: I believe that $|\frac{z^k}{z^k+1}| \le r^k$.

Pf: For $|z| \le r,$ we have $$|z|^k \le r^k \implies \frac{|z|^k}{r^k} \le 1. \tag{1}$$

But for $|z| \in [0,\infty),$ $$|z^k+1| \ge ||z^k|-|1|| = ||z|^k-1| \ge |0-1| = 1 \implies 1 \le |z^k+1| \tag{2}$$

Thus,

$$(1) \wedge (2) \implies \frac{|z|^k}{r^k} \le 1 \le |z^k+1| \implies \frac{|z|^k}{|z^k+1|} \le r^k$$

$$\therefore, |\frac{z^k}{z^k+1}| = \frac{|z^k|}{|z^k+1|} = \frac{|z|^k}{|z^k+1|} \le r^k \ \text{QED}$$

---

> [image]

Exer 7.30

Weierstrass M-Test: $|\frac{z}{w}|^k \le \frac{|z|^k}{r^k} = |\frac{z}{r}|^k =: M_k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In exercise 7.29 (c) 
$$\left\lvert \frac{z^k}{z^k+1} \right\rvert \leq r^k$$
doesn't hold for all of the $z \in \overline{D}[0,r]$. According to the maximum modulus principle, the maximum occurs on the boundary where $z=r \exp{i \theta}$. The functions to be maximized then become
$$\frac{r^k}{|r^k \exp{i k \theta}+1|},$$
and the maxima occur when $\exp{i k \theta}=-1$. Hence $M_k$ really should be $$M_k:=\frac{r^k}{1-r^{k}} .$$

Exericse 7.30 looks ok to me.

Comment: Thanks user1337, but what exactly is wrong with my argument please?

Comment: @BCLC Your choice of $M_k$.

Comment: lol I mean why? I believe it's an upper bound whose series is convergent

Comment: @BCLC It is not an upper bound. Consider $z=-r$ when $k$ is odd, for instance.

Comment: user1337, [WA seems to agree with you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C(z%5Ek)%2F(z%5Ek%2B1)%7C+%5Cle+r%5Ek,+z%3D-0.5,r%3D0.5,k%3D3). Thanks. Hmmmmmm...soooo what exactly is wrong with the argument I made above? I elaborated to hopefully make things more specific, explicit, clear, etc

Comment: @BCLC $||z|^k-1|\ge|0-1|$ is not necessarily true, consider $z=0.1$

Comment: @ErlangWiratamaSurya LOL THANKS!

Comment: @ErlangWiratamaSurya and user1337, okay so my method was wrong, but about the upper bound $r_k$, do you disagree with Mark Viola? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1802713/140308

Answer (score 0):

In re [user1337's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2870072/140308):

$$\frac{r^k}{1-r^{k}} \le \frac{r^k}{1-r}$$

Without user1337's answer, we can use [zhw.'s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802710) to directly show that:

$$|\frac{z^k}{1+z^k}| \le \frac{r^k}{1-r}$$

Note: Upper bound is a my proposed (albeit incorrect) upper bound multiplied by $\frac{1}{1-r}$. Note that $\frac{1}{1-r}$ does not depend on $k$.